# Create a 3D pca using Kmean with points labelled

Tags: r, pca

I want to make the plot given below on [mtcars dataset](https://gist.github.com/seankross/a412dfbd88b3db70b74b).[image].

For doing this I tried the code given [here](https://rpubs.com/StevedeP/pca) as follows:

```
require(rgl)
require(SciViews)
require(plotrix)
library(corrplot)
require(ggplot2)
require(reshape)
require("gridExtra")
cars.pca <- pcomp(~mpg+cyl+disp+hp+drat+wt+qsec, data = mtcars)#,  subset = -(8:14))
mtcars_pca = cbind(cbind(mtcars, cars.pca$scores), car = rownames(mtcars))
plot(cars.pca, which = "correlations") 
plot(cars.pca, which = "scores", cex = 0.8)
```

The code works fine until here and produces two plot as shown below:
[image: plot1]
[image: plot2]

Using the code given below the plot was made but there was problems in plot:

```
k <- kmeans(mtcars, 5, nstart=25, iter.max=1000)
new = cbind(mtcars_pca,cluster = k$cluster)
with(new,plot3d(PC1,PC2,PC3, col=k$cluster, size=2, type='s'))
car= = rownames(mtcars)
with(new,text3d(PC1,PC2,PC3,car))
```

[image: plot4]

The scale is not right,it is overlapping as shown in the plot the scale for pc1 has moved above and similarly pc2 and pc3 are overlapping,how these problems can be removed so that scale for pc1,pc2 and pc3 gets printed on right place?

Comment: You have 2 very simple mistakes: `new = cbind(mtcars_pca,cluster = k$cluster)` and `with(new,text3d(PC1,PC2,PC3,car))`

Comment: It is not an object, it is a column of `mtcars_pca` (`car = rownames(mtcars)`).

Comment: There are several options, but I recommend that you consult [`pca3d`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pca3d/vignettes/pca3d.pdf) and `ellipse3d` (from the `rgl` package).

Comment: I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you want to play with the parameters `aspect`, `adjust`, `cex` or use `jitter` to find values that minimize text overlap:

```
with(new,plot3d(PC1,PC2,PC3, col=k$cluster, size=2, type='s', aspect=c(3,1,3)))
car= rownames(mtcars)
with(new,text3d(jitter(PC1),jitter(PC2),jitter(PC3),car,cex=0.7, adjust=c(0.5,0.9)))
```

[image]

Comment: But the plot is confusing where is pc1, pc2 and pc3 in this plot?

Comment: PC1 axis is horizontal, PC3 axis is vertical and PC2 is perpendicular to both PC1 and PC3.